# $\min$ function properties

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

I need your help to get an insight on the $\min$ function:

Let $a,b \in [0,\infty)$, then it is known that:
$$ \frac{a+b}{2} \leq \max\left\lbrace a,b\right\rbrace \leq a+b$$

Is there a way to get the same inequality up to a multiplicative factor using the $\min$ function instead of $\max$ function?

If not, what inequalities can be derived using the $\min$ function?!

Please advise.

P.s. We are only interested in a lower bound!

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min(x,y)
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max(x,y)

Answer (score 0):

if $$\max\{a,b\}=a$$ if $$a\geq b$$ we have
$$\frac{a+b}{2}\le a$$ if $$b\le a$$
can you compute the other case?

Comment: It's known that $\min\left\lbrace a,b \right\rbrace = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( a + b - \left| a-b \right| \right)$.
It's hard to do the same inequalities, and even impossible, however can't we a lower bound on the $\min$ function?!

Answer (score 0):

If $a, b>0$ are nonzero, then $\min\{a,b\}=\frac{1}{\max\left\lbrace{1\over a},{1\over b}\right\rbrace}.$

Upload in the inequality you used
$$0<\frac{{1\over a}+{1\over b}}{2} \leq \max\left\lbrace {1\over a},{1\over b}\right\rbrace \leq {1\over a}+{1\over b}$$
we deduce
$$\frac{1}{{1\over a}+{1\over b}} \leq \min\left\lbrace a,b\right\rbrace \leq \frac{2}{{1\over a}+{1\over b}}$$
or 
$$\frac{ab}{a+b} \leq \min\left\lbrace a,b\right\rbrace \leq \frac{2ab}{a+b}$$

Comment: I noticed a recent comment of yours asking why some extremely poor questions get plenty of upvotes. The reason is that there are a handful of users on this site who deliberately protect cheaters and/or homework dumps. If you come across any blatantly poor questions, you can try flagging them for moderator attention, since they might help in clear-cut cases. Thank you for your support of question quality!